# Flask-talisman seems to break with any inline styles. What is the best way to override this?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to set up flask-talisman and can't seem to get it to work when I have any inline styles (using jinja2, flask, bootstrap).

My current (failed) configuration attempt looks like:

```
csp = {'default-src': "'self'",'script-src': ["'self'", 'cdn.plot.ly', 'cdn.jsdelivr.net', 'code.jquery.com','cdnjs.cloudflare.com', 'stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com'],'style-src': ["'self'", 'stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com', 'cdn.jsdelivr.net'],}

talis = Talisman()

# then inside my app factory:

talis.init_app(app, content_security_policy=csp, content_security_policy_nonce_in=['script-src'],)
```

Afterward I put `nonce="{{ csp_nonce() }}"` into all of my `<script> <link>` in my base jinja template. Finally, in chrome devtools I see:

> "Refused to apply inline style because it violates."

Appreciate any advice!!

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? Struggling with the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

@Matt Oestereich

I fixed this by adding `style-src` to both `CSP` and `content_security_policy_nonce_in`, like so:

```
csp = {
 'default-src': [
        '\'self\'',
        'maps.googleapis.com'
    ],
    'script-src': [
        '\'self\'',
        'code.jquery.com',
        'cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
        'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com'
    ],
    'style-src': [
    '\'self\'',
    'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com'
    ]
}

talisman = Talisman(
                    app,
                    content_security_policy=csp,
                    content_security_policy_nonce_in=['script-src', 'style-src']
)
```

This allowed me to use nonces in `<style>` elements.
I am now struggling with style within an element, such as `<ol style="someStyle">`. Currently, this gets blocked by talisman. Adding a nonce to `<ol>` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Looking at https://csplite.com/csp/test64/ allowing inline styling defeats the purpose of CSP. I've found either using <style> or stylesheets with nonce is the only thing that works in modern browsers.